# How to get value from input type hidden with Javascript in correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code

**HTML :**

```
<input type="hidden" name="test[]" id="test_0" value="123456789">
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(".test").each(function(){
   console.log('Test Value : '+ $(this).val());
});
```

**Result :**

> Test Value =

**The question :**

> Why result of console.log for $(this).val() inside my
>   Javascript code give result empty ? And how to fix it without change the Javascript code?

Thank you

Comment: The code shown would not log anything to the console, because you have no elements with the `"test"` class. If you are seeing `"Test Value ="` in the console there must be other elements not shown.

Comment: @nnnnnn : so what is your solution to fix that?

Comment: My point is that the result you say you are seeing is not possible with the code shown. Are you asking how to get the value of a single, specific input? If so, how do you want to identify that input? By id? By name? Or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn : if i don't want to change the Javascript but only change the HTML so how to fix it? you can post as an answer , if it solve the problem i will accept as correct answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$(".test")` targets the **class** `test`, not the **name** test. In order to solve that by only changing the HTML, simply give the input the relevant class:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test[]" class="test" id="test_0" value="123456789">
```

A working fiddle demonstrates this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1qLhuz/).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

test class is not defined.

try example,

```
console.log('Test Value : '+ $('#test_0').val());
```

Comment: that's correct, but i don't want to change Javascript, you only can change the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the desired element.

Try this:

```
$("#test_0").each(function(){
   console.log('Test Value : '+ $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: that's correct, but i don't want to change Javascript, you only can change the HTML code

Comment: If you want to change the HTML, add `class="test"` to your `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, you have to add a class to input

The problem, is that you are not getting any element, because you haven't any element with that class.
I think that's all.

Comment: <input class="test" type="hidden" name="test[]" id="test_0" value="123456789">